# Including other files than index.html to node.js using Socket IO

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I'm new to node.js so I do not know where I'm stuck but I need help. I started learning socket io and I can not include stylesheets to my website. I tried approaching the express method but it always returns of undefiend

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection',(socket)=>{
    console.log("uspeh");
    socket.on('poruka', (msg) => {
        io.emit('poruka',msg)
    });
});

http.listen(3000,()=>{
    console.log("Slusam na 3000");
});
```